# Exponentially bounded

Tags: probability, functions

What do you mean by a function being exponentially bounded? In the context of fat tailed distributions; tail being not exponentially bounded.

Answer (score 1):

there exist definition of this term  on a lot of site,for example

function $f(t)$ is called exponenetial bounded if there is always  such kind of criteria for all $t$

$f(t)<M*e^{k*t}$

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/Math17BHWDIRECTORY/ExpOrder.pdf

this may help you

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_distribution

please see

A fat-tailed distribution is a probability distribution that has the property, along with the other heavy-tailed distributions, that it exhibits large skewness or kurtosis. This comparison is often made relative to the normal distribution, or to the exponential distribution. Fat-tailed distributions have been empirically encountered in a variety of areas: economics, physics, and earth sciences. Some fat-tailed distributions have power law decay in the tail of the distribution, but do not necessarily follow a power law everywhere.

The distribution of a random variable X is said to have a fat tail if
[image]

it is like a power,not exponential

Comment: Could you throw some light on the fat tailed distribution part?

Comment: in a few minute i will try ok?maybe someone else will help you

Comment: I did go through wiki before posting question here.I kind of got confused between power law and exponential before(thought both were same;silly). Your last line cleared though.Thanks @dato

Comment: you are welcome friend